# Boost circuit for LCD matrix display

Tags: lcd, boost

I'm using the hitachi 66720 controller for the diplay and there is a boost schematics which helps to provide enough current for the display. Here how it looks like:

[image: 1]

I don't understand how transistor is used here. And why there is a thermistor? 
The purpose is to stabilize the voltage in the Vci pin but not sure how this is done here.
I would like to see some explanations on this schematics.
Thanks

Comment: The Contrast control is temperature sensitive. Most hobby projects ignore that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimum voltage on the Vci pin is temperature-dependent. The resistor chain approximates that optimal voltage over some temperature range. The transistor buffers that voltage, presumably because the Vci pin requires a lower impedance than what is reasonably achieved with a resistive divider.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Why it is temperature dependent? I believe to make the brightness constant. So Vci must remain constant and thermistor must compensate the changes in the resistance over the changing temperature. But i'm not sure.

Comment: No, the optimal Vci voltage is different for different temperatures, for instance 4.2V at 20C, 4.0V at 25C, etc.

Comment: That's strange. Why it is designed to be temperature dependent? Probably because the supply current for the LCD is changing? But the thermistor is not on the LCD. It pretty far from the LCD on the board.

Comment: It is not *designed* to be termperature dependent, it *is* so. LCDs depend on a physical effect (change of polarization due to orientation of molecules in an electric field) which is inherently temperature-dependent.